# MySQL error using resque with rails table does not exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, resque, mysql2

Edit: Ok I've posted my code on this repository here https://github.com/willnance/doctor-self-study

Hoping someone can take a look at it. I'm at wits end. I've looked at every single example I can find and cannot figure this out. No matter how I change the parameters for `enqueue_at(` the error doesn't change. If I don't pass any argument and try to `enqueue_at(` then I get  `wrong number of arguments 0 for 1`  at the same line -- the declaration of the `perform` method of my job. Absolutely baffling.

There's not a single post online about this specific error.

furthermore if anyone has any recommendations about how to debug this that would be awesome. I'm running netbeans 7.1 IDE with the open source ruby / rails plugin on windows and haven't been able to find a debugging method.

end edit.

I've set up a rails app with resque_scheduler. I intend to deploy it to heroku soon (using that nifty autoscaling code that floats about on the internet) but I'm trying to iron out the kinks locally. i opened up the resque-web interface and noticed that I had 10 failed jobs ( -*_*- )

All of them have the exact same error message. I cant even really wrap my head around what's going wrong. Its looking for  `doctor_self_study_development.id` , which is basically the app name, the environment and `.id.` I really don't understand why this is happening.

```
Worker
PCNAME-HP:12188 on READY_QUEUE at just now Retry or Remove
Class
 SchedulerJob
Arguments
{"id"=>40}
Exception
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
Error
Mysql2::Error: Table 'doctor self study_development.id' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `id`
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `query'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:257:in `execute_and_free'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:424:in `columns'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:16:in `yield'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:16:in `default'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:16:in `block in initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:56:in `yield'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:56:in `default'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:56:in `block in build_from_hash'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:4:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:4:in `map'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:4:in `build_from_hash'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:13:in `block in build_from_hash'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:4:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:4:in `map'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:4:in `build_from_hash'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:327:in `build_where'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:136:in `where'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:264:in `find_by_attributes'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
C:/Users/Will Nance/Dropbox/Eclipse/Ruby on Rails Development/sample Heroku/app/jobs/scheduler_job.rb:8:in `perform'
```

So seeing that the error is happening in the perform method, here is the job class thats doing the lifting here:

```
#ALL jobs and models must extend the Autoscaling module for cheap Heroku deployment
require 'heroku_resque_auto_scale'
class SchedulerJob 
  extend HerokuAutoScaler::AutoScaling
  @queue = :ready_queue
  def self.perform(id)
    @assignment=Assignment.find_by_id(id)
    @assignment.sendAlertEmail
  end
end
```

and finally here is the model with the callback `on_create` that triggers enqueue_at()

```
require "scheduler_job"
#ALL jobs and models must extend the Autoscaling module for cheap Heroku deployment
require 'heroku_resque_auto_scale'
class Assignment  ActiveRecord::Base extend HerokuAutoScaler::AutoScaling
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :user_id, :question_id , :response , :correct
  after_create :queue_assignments
  before_destroy :remove_from_queue

  def grade
    self.correct = (response == self.question.solution) unless response == nil
  end
  def queue_assignments
    Resque.enqueue_at(self.question.schedule , SchedulerJob , :id => self.id)
  end
  def remove_from_queue
    Resque.remove_delayed(SchedulerJob, :id => self.id)
  end
  def sendAlertEmail
    QuestionMailer.question(self)
  end
  def as_json(options={})
    {
      :correct => correct,
      :created_at =>  created_at,
      :id => id, 
      :question_id => question_id,
      :response => response ,
      :updated_at => updated_at,
      :user_id => user_id,
      :question => self.question
    }
  end
end
```

Here are the `resque.rake` and `resque.rb`

resque.rake

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks'
require 'resque_scheduler/server'
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end
task "resque:scheduler_setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

resque.rb

```
require 'resque_scheduler'
require 'resque/server'


ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] ||=   "redis://redistogo:f95d214230c8ec72a902bbd2b519dbe3@spinyfin.redistogo.com:9192/"


require 'resque'
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/jobs/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }

uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

I'd appreciate any explanation of what's going on here and some pointers on how to fix it.

Comment: Was this ever working?  If so, what's changed since it last worked?  I notice your database names in your `config/database.yml` have spaces in them, and in particular your development database is called `doctor self study_development`, which you can see in the MySQL error you're getting.

Comment: There's a bunch of other wacky things going on in that repo.  A `.gitignore` file and a `.git ignore` file?  Rails and Sinatra in your Gemfile?  No tests?  A `test` directory full of sub-directories and (essentially) empty files?  It's also generally a good idea to use the same DBMS in development as you use in production.  Since you're using Heroku, and hence PostgreSQL, have you tried switching your development environment to use that?